# Finding GCD in $\mathbb{Z}_m[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Given the polynomials $x^3+x^2+x$ and $x^2+x+1$, I want to find the gcd in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$.

I know that $x^3+x^2+x=(x^2+x+1)(x)+0$. I can't tell if there's more to this question or is the gcd simply $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$. Thanks!

Comment: gcd is the common irreducible factor of both polynomials in the field. For higher dimensions, there are standard algorithms like rabin's algorithm, risch algorithm

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + x + 1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ as pointed out in the comment and irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_m[x] $ for $m =5,11$ hence, the gcd is $(x-1)^2$ for $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$and $x^2+x+1$ for the other two fields.

Comment: @vadim123 thanks, I made the appropriate edits.

Comment: The first part is still wrong; for example, $x^2+x+1=(x+3)(x-2)$, in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.  On what basis do you believe $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible?

Comment: @vadim123 extremely thankful. I believed since $x^2+x+1$ is cyclotomic, hence it was irreducible in any $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm confused now as to why the gcd is $x-1$ instead of $x^2-2x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ since by definition the gcd, if $d$ is the gcd of $f,g$ and $e$ divides $f$ and $g$, then deg$(e)\leq$deg$(d)$

Comment: @J-P thanks for your question. The gcd is $(x-1)^2$ which is divisible by $x^2+x+1$